# Adding tools in UDO in SAP Business one

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hana, sapb1

I have created my User Defined Object in SAP. I use SAP Business one 9.0. But this UDO is not as I want.

I want to add some tools (Textboxes, Comboboxes, Buttons and others) to it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

To add new UI fields (`Item`s), you'll need to use the SAP UI API.

If you have the SAP SDK installed, which I'd certainly recommend, there are examples in the installation folder.